# Queue implementation with linked lists in C

Tags: c, queue, linked-list, android-ndk

Below is the implementation of my queue, which has functionality of enqueueing and dequeing from the Queue. Because of some reason it is crashing with no clues(where it is crashing), as the code is running on android. I suspect with my queue code. If you guys have any clue, what's wrong with my code, please give me an idea.

Thanks for any help.

Here is my C Code :

```
    int qLast = 0;

typedef struct phoneSt PhoneStructure;

typedef struct{
    PhoneStructure Phone;
    struct phoneQ *next;
}phoneQ;


phoneQ *headElement = NULL;    /* front pointer in queue*/
phoneQ *tailElement = NULL;     /* rear pointer in queue */

void enqueue_Phone(PhoneStructure Frame)
{
    phoneQ *newnode;      /* New node to be inserted */
    newnode=(phoneQ*)av_malloc(sizeof(phoneQ));
    newnode->next=NULL;
    newnode->Phone=Frame;
        qLast++;
    if(headElement==NULL && tailElement==NULL)
    {
        headElement=newnode;
        tailElement=newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        tailElement->next=newnode;
        tailElement=newnode;
                                                                                                                   }
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "myphone.c", "Queue is having %d element", qLast);
}

PhoneStructure dequeue_Phone()
{
    phoneQ *delnode;      /* Node to be deleted */
    PhoneStructure Frame;
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "myplayer.c", "In dequeue_Phone");
    if(headElement==NULL && tailElement==NULL){
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "myphone.c", "Queue is empty to delete any element");
        }
    else
    {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "myphone.c", "In dequeue  queue is not empty");
        delnode=headElement;
        headElement=headElement->next;
        Frame = delnode->Phone;
        av_free(delnode);
        qLast--;
    }
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "myphone.c", "In dequeue_Phone returning  remaining  %d",qLast);
        return Frame;
}
```

Comment: dequeue_phone and enqueue_phone are called from different threads and synchronisation is using qLast, if it is less than 1, then there'll be no dequeueing. I suspect that the problem is in dequeue_phone. Let me know if anybody found some problem with this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you empty the queue you do not set tailElement to NULL. Next time you enqueue, headElement will remain null, and you will access the deleted tailElement which *may* crash. If it doesn't, when you dequeue, you access headElement->next, which *will* crash.

```
...
headElement=headElement->next;
if (!headElement)
    tailElement=NULL;
Frame = delnode->Phone;
...
```

Comment: I was about to say the same thing, but would add based on the original author's comment subsequent to your post that the code — even as fixed — isn't thread safe. E.g. the act of setting the queue back to empty at dequeue isn't atomic, so could overlap with the act of enqueueing a new node to a queue that is believed not to be empty. The author would be better off to use a mutex to ensure only one thread is accessing anything to do with the queue at a time.

Answer (score 0):

When **you are deleting the element** you must make a check whether **head->next==NULL** or not.Since if this is true then you must set tail to NULL as this is must be last node in the linked list.Hope this would make your program run.